# Method to delete object from Linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I do not see my mistake, correct me, please!
I need to delete an object from Linkedlist. But I got an error NPE in `if (current.item.equals(e))`

```
   public void remove(T e) {
        if (first == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is empty");
        }
        if (first.item.equals(e)) {
            first = first.next;
            first.next.prev = null;

        }
        if (last.item.equals(e)) {
            last = last.prev;
            last.prev.next = null;
        } else {
            Node<T> current = first;
            for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
                current = current.next;
                if (current.item.equals(e)) {
                    current.prev.next = current.next;
                    current.next.prev = current.prev;

                }

            }
            size--;
            System.out.println("Removed");
        }
    }
```

```
Linkedlist<String> list = new Linkedlist<>();
        list.put("Maria");
        list.put("Ales");
        list.put("zina");
        list.put("bina");
        list.put("fina");
        

        list.remove("zina");
```

Comment: It's possible `first.item`, `first.next`, `last.item`, or `last.prev` are `null`.

Comment: @akash why it is a mistake? I want to delete an object from the middle

Comment: @bhxbr922 suppose you have 2 nodes. then `first = first.next;` now you have one node and you already on the next node. So no more next node. So should be `first.prev = null;` but your code had   `first.next.prev = null;`for last node also last.next = null; And sorry rest has no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your code is too optimistic. There are several boundary cases you should check for `null` values.
- The code blocks that deal with a match of the first or last node, rewire the wrong node.
- The `size` value is not adjusted when the first or last node is removed
- When no match is found, `size` is still decremented.

Corrected version with comments:

```
public void remove(T e) {
    if (first == null) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is empty");
    }
    if (first.item.equals(e)) {
        first = first.next;
        // first can be null now!
        if (first != null) {
            // As you already moved the `first` reference, you should not go to next:
            first.prev = null;
        }
    } else if (last.item.equals(e)) { // make this an else if
        last = last.prev;
        // As you already moved the `last` reference, you should not go to prev:
        last.next = null;
    } else {
        Node<T> current = first.next;  // can go to next here already
        // avoid current to be null, so make it the loop condition
        while (current) {
            if (current.item.equals(e)) {
                current.prev.next = current.next;
                current.next.prev = current.prev;
                // No need to continue. Just exit here
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (current == null) return; // Not found! We should not decrement the size
    }
    // Size must be decremented here, since it also applies to head/tail removals!
    size--;
    System.out.println("Removed");
}
```

#### Remarks:

- After `last = last.prev;` we can be sure that `last` is not `null`. If it were, then the original value of `last` was equal to `first`, and then we would never have gotten here.
- In the `if (current.item.equals(e)) {` block, we can be sure that both `current.prev` and `current.next` are not null. If they would have been, then `current` would represent the first/last node, for which we had already concluded that they were not a match.
- I assumed that all nodes are guaranteed to have an `item` property.
- I assumed that at most *one* node should be removed